# Ajax doubles calls to success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following js code:

```
$('#btn_goals').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Goals/Index',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#region_content').html(data);
            console.log("goals fires");
        }
    });
});
```

It fires on some button click and works perfect except one weird thing: it fires once on the first button click, twice on the second, fourfold on the third and so on.

Here is google console output:

```
1st click:
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
content loaded  myscript-002.js:8

2nd click:
content loaded  myscript-002.js:8
content loaded  VM43:8

3rd click:
content loaded  myscript-002.js:8
content loaded  VM43:8
content loaded  VM43:8
content loaded  VM43:8
```

and so on.

What is the reason?

Comment: You've placed that event handler inside another event handler

Comment: Looks like the `$('#btn_goals').on('click', function () {..})` is executed multiple times

Comment: Yes, a added console.log("button clicks") in the beginning of my handler method just before ajax invoke. It seems to be fire multiple times too. But I click it only once each time, you may believe me

Comment: u can try to make ajax call asyn false

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is with registering of same event multiple times, then use this ..

```
 $('#btn_goals').off('click');
 $('#btn_goals').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Goals/Index',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#region_content').html(data);
                console.log("goals fires");
            }
        });
    });
```

**`off()`** method clears the previous event attached using on() method.

**2nd Method #updated**

```
       $(document).off("userDistinctData");
        $(document).on("userDistinctData", function (e) {    
        performAjaxCall();
        }
        );

     var performDataCall = function () {
       $.ajax({
            url: '/Goals/Index',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#region_content').html(data);
                console.log("goals fires");
            }
        });
     };

 $('#btn_goals').off('click');
 $('#btn_goals').on('click', function () {
   $(document).trigger({
                        type: "userDistinctData",
                        cData: data,
                    });
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't help

Comment: Then there is some other problem in your code ... Use the 2nd method i have posted above in my answer to give another try ...

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable explanation based on the code and information you provided is, that whatever you get back in HTML code from your *AJAX request*, also creates a *click event handler* on the same element `#btn_goals`. Most likely, with the identical code.

So examine the result for the request and fix that if necessary.

Comment: Well, the code above is actualy all I have. What does it mean "also creates handler"? Where can I see it?

Comment: If I remove $.ajax call the button handler invokes once at a click. But when I add ajax call clicks start to double every time